# Изменения состояние объекта в массиве объектов. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть некий массив полей получаемый из базы данных. Эти поля передаются в компонент для создания пункта в таблице. Каждое поле содержит имя к примеру "телефон" или "адрес". Это делается для того, что бы при добавлении нового пункта он соответственно отобразился при создании. Дальше на основе полученных полей создаются input(ы) и мне нужно собрать с каждого input(а) значение и поместить его в массив объектов. Кульминация того к чему я пришел это:

```js
onChange={({ target }) => {
  const { name, value } = target

  setQuery(query => ({
    ...query,
    fields: [
      ...query.fields,
      {
        name,
        value
      }
    ]
  }))
}}
```

где как результат

```js
fields: (23) […]
​​
0: Object { name: "Телефон", value: "ы" }
​​
1: Object { name: "Телефон", value: "ыа" }
​​
2: Object { name: "Телефон", value: "ыау" }
​​
3: Object { name: "Телефон", value: "ыауы" }
​​
4: Object { name: "Телефон", value: "ыауыу" }
​​
5: Object { name: "Телефон", value: "ыауыуа" }
​​
6: Object { name: "Адрес", value: "ф" }
​​
7: Object { name: "Адрес", value: "фы" }
​​
8: Object { name: "Адрес", value: "фыа" }
​​
9: Object { name: "Адрес", value: "фыаф" }
​​
10: Object { name: "Адрес", value: "фыафы" }
​​
11: Object { name: "Адрес", value: "фыафыа" }
​​
12: Object { name: "Адрес", value: "фыафыау" }
​​
13: Object { name: "Почта", value: "ф" }
​​
14: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фы" }
​​
15: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фыа" }
​​
16: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фыаф" }
​​
17: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фыафы" }
​​
18: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фыафыу" }
​​
19: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фыафыуа" }
​​
20: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фыафыуаы" }
​​
21: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фыафыуаыу" }
​​
22: Object { name: "Почта", value: "фыафыуаыуа" }
```

Сил больше нет. Памагите!

Comment: Если честно, то ничего не понятно. Закинь [сюда](https://codesandbox.io/) то, что есть на данный момент.

Comment: В целом этот код описывает проблему 
https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-hill-q63bd

Comment: Попозже посмотрю что там

Comment: Так а что у тебя не получается? Неправильно state формируется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема в том, что неправильно формируется state, то [вот одно из возможных решений](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-matsumoto-q34l1).

Если покажется, что это невозможно понять, а мозг будет кричать *закрой эту вкладку, я сейчас взорвусь* - встань и сделай зарядку, потому что это реально тяжеловато понять. Можешь [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121272/whats-the-best-way-to-update-an-object-in-an-array-in-reactjs) ещё посмотреть возможные инструменты к решению твоей проблемы.

Comment: Вообще, в твоем примере куда проще было бы сделать поле `fields` объектом, но я думаю ты не спроста выбрал такой путь )

Comment: В проекте сама задача необычная, нативным скриптом уже сделал бы. Но у реакта свое мнение по этому поводу. С кодом разобрался. Спасиба